# PHP if statement to check if value existis in a column that holds an array

Tags: php, sql

I have a field that stores multiple zip codes. 
A query result for the zip codes column may contain several zip codes: 90027,90028,90068

I need an if statement to check if a single zip code is in the result

```
$zipstring = $rows['pool_zip_codes']);

$zipsql = "SELECT `pool_zip_codes` FROM `cases` WHERE `id` = '{$rowid}' AND `pool_zip_codes` IN ('{$zipstring}') ";

$zipqry = mysql_query($zipsql);
$zipresult = mysql_fetch_row($zipqry);

if (($zipresult[0]) == '90068') { 
this zip code is in the list
} else {
not in list
}
};
```

Comment: *I have a field that stores multiple zip codes* have you considered changing your database structure? Putting lots of information like that in one field is often a bad thing, such as having to write funky code to do this which would be easy if your database was designed differently.

Comment: Strong hint - look into PDO - it's easy, and `mysql_*` is deprecated. (Won't solve this particular problem though)

Comment: OK, I have to select by multiple zip codes that can access 1 case. How should I show a user only the cases that contain their zip code?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you want to distinguish between

```
#####
```

and

```
#####,#####,#####...
```

To do this, just use a regex to check if the field matches 5 digits.

```
if (preg_match("/^\d{5}$/", $zipresult[0])) {
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, as the others are saying, use `in_array()`.  What they're not saying is that you'd have to `explode()` the string first, to make an array:

```
$exploded = explode(",", $zipresult[0]);

if (in_array($exploded, "99999")) {
    ....
}
```

---

**EDIT** per your comment you could use `strpos()`

```
$targetcode = "99999";
$found = array();
foreach ($zipresult as $row) {
    if (strpos($row['pool_zip_codes'], $targetcode) !== false) {
        $found[] = $row;
    }   
}
```

or `in_array()`

```
$targetcode = "99999";
$found = array();
foreach ($zipresult as $row) {
    $exploded = explode(",", $row['pool_zip_codes']);
    if (in_array($exploded, $targetcode)) {
       $found[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$zipresult = mysql_fetch_array($zipqry);

if (($zipresult['pool_zip_codes']) == '90068') {
this zip code is in the list
} else {
not in list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `in_array()`

as

```
if (in_array($zipresult[0],$zipresult)) 
{ 
echo "this zip code is in the list" ;
} 
else { 
echo "not in list"; 
}
```

Comment: This won't work because `$zipresult[0]` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and use `in_array`:

```
if (in_array(explode(',', $zipresult[0]),$zipresult)) 
{ 
   #this zip code is in the list
} 
else { 
   #not in list
}
```